# D3 Multi-Series Line Chart with ZOOM

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Apologies for the newbie question here. I'm trying to reproduce this example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955 with some data on online influencers (essentially drawing many lines) but with an scroll zoom in order to isolate parts of the data. Sounds simple enough, but I can't seem to get it to function!

```js
< svg width = "960"
height = "500" > < /svg>
<script src="/ / d3js.org / d3.v4.min.js "></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 100},
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform ", "translate(" + margin.left +
          ", " + margin.top + ")"); 

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 32])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var parseTime = d3.timeParse(" % d / % m / % Y ");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.engagement); });

d3.csv("stack2.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var influencers = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
    return {
      id: id,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, engagement: d[id]};
      })
    };
  });


  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([d3.min(influencers, function(c) { 
       return d3.min(c.values, function(d) { 
           return d.engagement; }); }),
 d3.max(influencers, function(c) { 
       return d3.max(c.values, function(d) { 
           return d.engagement; }); })
  ]);

  z.domain(influencers.map(function(c) { return c.id; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 5)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .text("Engagement");

 var influ = g.selectAll(".influ")
  .data(influencers)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "influ");

influ.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.values);
  })
  .style("stroke", "lightgrey")
  .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).transition()
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return z(d.id);
      })
      .style("stroke-width", 3)
    console.log(d.id);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    d3.select(this).transition()
      .style("stroke", "lightgrey")
      .style("stroke-width", 1)
  })


influ.append("text")
  .datum(function(d) {
    return {
      id: d.id,
      value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
    };
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.engagement) + ")";
  })
  .attr("x", 3)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("opacity", 0.7)
  .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.id;
  });

svg.call(zoom)

});

function type(d, _, columns) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  for (var i = 1, n = columns.length, c; i < n; ++i) d[c = columns[i]] = +d[c];
  return d;
}

function zoomed() {
  var t = d3.event.transform,
    xt = t.rescaleX(x);
  g.selectAll("path.line").attr("d", function(d) {
    return xt(d.date);
  });
  g.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis.scale(xt));
}

< /script>
```

I think the problem is isolated to this part:

```
function zoomed() {
  var t = d3.event.transform,
    xt = t.rescaleX(x);
  g.selectAll("path.line").attr("d", function(d) {
    return xt(d.date);
  });
  g.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis.scale(xt));
}
```

The Axis zoom is fine, but i don't think I'm calling the data for the line graphs correctly. I think g.selectAll definitely selects the lines, as they disappear on scroll... so I am assuming that `.attr("d", function(d) {return xt(d.date);` is wrong. Anyone have any tips?

Comment: I've got it to work... but in a very unsophisticated fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use something along these lines in an interactive line chart D3 plot that I wrote a couple of days back. I've commented extensively, so it should be pretty self explanatory. This works really well and has been bug free.

```
function zoomed() {
  lastEventTransform = d3.event.transform;

  // Rescale axes using current zoom transform
  gX.call(xAxis.scale(lastEventTransform.rescaleX(x)));
  gY.call(yAxis.scale(lastEventTransform.rescaleY(y)));

  // Create new scales that incorporate current zoom transform on original scale
  var xt = lastEventTransform.rescaleX(x),
      yt = lastEventTransform.rescaleY(y);

  // Apply new scale to create new definition of d3.line method for path drawing of line plots
  var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { return xt(d.x); })
      .y(function(d) { return yt(d.y); });

  // Update all line-plot elements with new line method that incorporates transform
  innerSvg.selectAll(".line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });

  // Update any scatter points if you are also plotting them
  innerSvg.selectAll(".dot")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {return xt(d.x); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {return yt(d.y); });
}
```

Note: `gX` and `gY` are just the d3 `g` group elements that had the axes originally called on them during setup of the plot.

Comment: Thanks for this. One more quick question: What is innerSvg referring to?

Comment: Ah, so `innerSvg` is a nested SVG block that is of the size of only the plotting area (rectangle with the 2 axes as its sides). I plot all my lines/circles in the inner SVG. The reason for this is that `g` elements do not clip SVG elements. So when you zoom into your plot, the lines and circles end up being plotted outside the axes (in the area where ticks and labels are). Some people use a CSS clip attribute to prevent this for the g elements but it doesn't work so well if you are using brushes to zoom.

Comment: @HGalan - Did this answer help with your issue?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I implemented your code and the axis zoom is nice and smooth. I still can't get it to 'zoom' on the lines (it is definitely selecting them right, because they disappear). I think i'm making a mistake elsewhere in my code! thanks for your help nonetheless...

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. It would be great if you could mark the reply as having answered your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

This Zoom function tricks the domain to change and then redraws the lines on the new domain. Its the best i can manage for now... but hardly elegant!

```
function zoomed() {
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  // var t = d3.event.scaleBy;
  var xt = t.rescaleY(y);
  domain = yAxis.scale().domain();
  g.select(".axis--y").call(yAxis.scale(xt));

  g.selectAll("path.line").attr("d", function(d) { 
    if ( d3.max(d.values.map(function(dd) { return dd.engagement } )) > domain[1] ) {
      return null
    }
    else {
      return line(d.values)
    }
   });



  if (domain[1] > 50000000) {
    max = 50000000
  } else if ( domain[1] < 500 ) {
    max = 500
  } else {
    max = domain[1]
  }

  y.domain([0, max]);
}
```

It zooms alright but it is prone to de-coupling the axis from what the lines are saying. If anyone has something better let me know!